# phpCAS - Make calls to HTTP:// and not HTTPS://

Tags: java, php, authentication, ssl, cas

I'm using phpCAS to attempt to authenticate my users with a central credentials system.

Currently in the development cycle so CAS isn't behind SSL, therefore the url is at HTTP://

I can't seem to get phpCAS to go there even though I'm using the no SSL validation for CAS server line:

```
phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
```

My code is exactly as shown in the simple example here: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS+examples

The only difference is my server host name (www.mysite.com), and port is (8080).

Anyone know how to get the redirect to go to HTTP:// instead of HTTPS:// ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Solving+SSL+issues.  CAS server **requires** SSL.  After all, an authentication system needs to be as secure and trustworthy as possible.  It would be a better use of your time to go ahead and configure your CAS server to use SSL with a self-signed certificate, rather than trying to find out how to bypass the SSL mechanisms.

The [phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation()](http://downloads.jasig.org/cas-clients/php/current/docs/api/group__publicAuth.html#gacff185b5b08e4ff603d0f6f1cb76e4ce) method is for situations where the server is using a self-signed certificate or a certificate that hasn't been signed by a Certificate Authority that's recognized and trusted by the client.  It tells the client to simply accept the certificate as-is without doing any further checking to validate it.